# C# Selenium Firefox not able to send string to input; visible but webElement value does not change

Tags: c#, selenium, input, sendkeys

In c# Selenium using FireFox, 
I want to send text to an input.

My code looks like this:

```
IWebElement dosar = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"Text5\"]"));
dosar.SendKeys(textBox1.Text);
dosar.Click();
dosar.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
```

The problem is that the text from `textBox1.Text` gets placed in input, it is visible, but at the next line of code where it shoud send Enter Key, the program behaves like no text is placed in input.
So, I can see it, it is there, but the code does not see its value.

I created a string string `dateDosar = dosar.Text.ToString();` to check what value has the element after sending the text.
In debugger the result of this string is null (it shows: `dateDosar = ""`).

So it seems although the value is there in input and it is visible, the program does not see it.

Also, the above mentioned code works fine in Chrome and IE, but does not work in FireFox.

In FireFox works only if I run it in debugger mode.
I placed a break at the line where I send the text to input `dosar.SendKeys(textBox1.Text)`

If I then press "Continue" to run the program after the break, it works fine.

So, the code works in debugger mode, but does not work if I run it without debugger.

I get no errors, no exceptions, but due to the fact that the program does not see the text from the input, it redirects me on a wrong web page where, of course, it does not find the webElements from my code.

Comment: Is `textbox1` an `<input type="text">` element?

Comment: textBox1 is an input from WindowsForms. In that I place a string (actually it is a file number, something like this 1000/100/2019) that should be used to direct me on the page of the file (using a browser)

Comment: ??? from WindowsForms? As in the WindowsForms framework? Is this text input part of a client Windows application? So you are taking input from an installed client app and typing it into a web page?

Comment: there is a windows forms input where you type the string. I try to automathize the search of files. it opens a browser app connected to a local data base and it shoul take the string froms the form, place it in the input of the opens (FireFox) browser and then navigate to a certain page

Comment: Is there a submit button you can click instead on the web page?

Comment: Which version of Firefox and FirefoxDriver are you using? Sometimes these issues arise from incompatible Firefox and FirefoxDriver versions.

Comment: You might just need to use `driver.ExecuteScript(...)` to do this in JavaScript instead. Use JavaScript to set the value on the `<input>` and then use JavaScript to submit the form.

Comment: any reason for "dosar.Click();"?  That seems odd to me.  Maybe try without it.

Comment: Isn't there a Submit button or something like that on the form? Try clicking that instead of sending ENTER. Most likely what's happening is that the initial text is being cleared and replaced by the ENTER key. I've seen this before with TAB.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

From a comment:

> it is visible physically, but I can not access it in FireFox (only in IE, where I can click it). So, in FireFox I would have this possibility of entering the text in input box and then send Enter Key.

This makes me think an element on the page is interfering with Selenium some how. A JavaScript solution may work instead:

```cs
var executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

// Enter the value in the form field:
executor.ExecuteScript($@"document.getElementById(""Text5"").value = ""{textBox1.Text}"";");

// Submit the form
executor.ExecuteScript($@"document.getElementById(""Text5"").form.submit();");
```

---

**Original Answer:**

Since it runs find in debug mode and are stepping through things line by line, it might be a wonky race condition causing the failure. The combination of `SendKeys` + `Click` + `SendKeys` again might be causing it. Try clicking, then waiting for a brief moment before sending the keys, including the "ENTER" key all in one call to `SendKeys`:

```cs
dosar.Click();
// pause for half a second to ensure JavaScript event handlers process fully
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
dosar.SendKeys(textBox1.Text + OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
```

If this does not work, clicking a "submit" button and forgoing the ENTER key should work:

```cs
dosar.SendKeys(textBox1.Text);

// Note: Change 'Search' to the real button text
var submitButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(., 'Search')]"));

submitButton.Click();
```

Comment: I tried your first approach. It still doesn,t work. I can not implement second approach because I do have a submit button in browser, but I have the same problem with it: it is visible physically, but I can not access it in FireFox (only in IE, where I can click it). So, in FireFox I would have this possibility of entering the text in input box and then send Enter Key. Thanks Greg.

Comment: @claudiudradusin, I bet an element on the page is overlapping the text field in Firefox, but not in IE. I think I have an idea...

Comment: I think it may also be related to the webdriver.exe; I added some refferences from nuGet, namely different drivers for chrome and with one of them I had the same problem (in chrome) even thou with the original driver I did not. So maybe it is something related to selenium and the way it interacts whit the drivers. JavaScript solution you mentioned did not work. I had already tried it. Anyways, I found a way around finding a way to use chrome. So, I abandoned FireFox and thus I have no more problems whit it :) . Thank you for your messages, Greg!

Comment: Please post which version of Firefox you have, and which version of FirefoxDriver you are using. I bet that is the issue. You need the right version combo to get things working right.